# GNUStep make problems

Tags: objective-c, makefile, gnustep

I have installed the GNUStep gnustep-msys-system-0.29.0-setup.exe and gnustep-core-0.29.1-setup.exe on my WinXp Machine

I am able to compile problems. The documentation says that gnustep-core comes with the make utility but I am unable to locate it or use it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everything is installed correctly, `jacekmigacz`'s answer may work.

However, an easier path might be to simply install Linux.  That will give you the ability to trivially install GNUStep and LLVM.

Alternatively, grab the GNUStep Live CD (http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/GNUstep_Live_CD).

Answer (score 0):

```
cd gnustep/core/make
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: my windows installation of gnustep does not have a core or a mke directory it just has a directory called System